# ¿Cómo listar los empleados sin repetir? LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

intento listar los empleados que han realizado servicios, el problema es que no sé como hacer la consulta con linq y con este código que les dejo me listan dos veces el mismo empleado.

He notado que si tengo registrado dos servicios distintos con el mismo empleado se me listará el empleado dos veces. Solo quiero que se me liste los empleados que hayan realizado servicios pero que estos no se repitan.

```
    public List<EmpleadoDTO> Consultar_Empleados()
    {
        Model1 Entity = new Model1();

        var datos = (from i in Entity.EMPLEADO
                     where i.ESTADO == true
                     select i).ToList();

        List<EmpleadoDTO> oEmpleadoDTO = new List<EmpleadoDTO>();

        foreach (var item in datos)
        {
            EmpleadoDTO oEmpleado = new EmpleadoDTO();
            var servicio = (from i in Entity.VENTA_SERVICIO
                            where i.COD_EMPLEADO == item.ID_EMPLEADO
                            select i).FirstOrDefault();

            var Cargo = (from i in Entity.CARGO
                         where i.COD_CARGO == item.CARGO
                         select i).FirstOrDefault();

            var Rol = (from i in Entity.ROL
                       where i.COD_ROL == item.ROL
                       select i).FirstOrDefault();

            var tipodoc = (from i in Entity.TIPODOCUMENTO
                           where i.COD_DOCUMENTO == item.TIPO_DOCUMENTO
                           select i).FirstOrDefault();

            oEmpleado.ID_EMPLEADO = item.ID_EMPLEADO;
            oEmpleado.NOMBRE_CARGO = Cargo.NOMBRE;
            oEmpleado.NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO = tipodoc.NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO;
            oEmpleado.NOMBRE = item.NOMBRE;
            oEmpleado.ROL = item.ROL;
            oEmpleado.APELLIDO = item.APELLIDO;
            oEmpleado.CEDULA_EMPLEADO = item.CEDULA_EMPLEADO;
            oEmpleado.CELULAR = item.CELULAR;
            oEmpleado.CARGO = Cargo.COD_CARGO;

            oEmpleadoDTO.Add(oEmpleado);
        }
        return oEmpleadoDTO;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cambia

```
return oEmpleadoDTO;
```

por

```
return oEmpleadoDTO.DistinctBy(i => i.ID_EMPLEADO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, siento por hacer esta pregunta sin notar que puedo poner una condición después de la consulta "servicio" que está dentro del foreach.

```
    public List<EmpleadoDTO> Consultar_Empleados()
    {
        Model1 Entity = new Model1();

        var datos = (from i in Entity.EMPLEADO
                     where i.ESTADO == true
                     select i).ToList();

        List<EmpleadoDTO> oEmpleadoDTO = new List<EmpleadoDTO>();

        foreach (var item in datos)
        {
            EmpleadoDTO oEmpleado = new EmpleadoDTO();
            var servicio = (from i in Entity.VENTA_SERVICIO
                            where i.COD_EMPLEADO == item.ID_EMPLEADO
                            select i).FirstOrDefault();

            if (servicio != null)
            {
                var Cargo = (from i in Entity.CARGO
                             where i.COD_CARGO == item.CARGO
                             select i).FirstOrDefault();

                var Rol = (from i in Entity.ROL
                           where i.COD_ROL == item.ROL
                           select i).FirstOrDefault();

                var tipodoc = (from i in Entity.TIPODOCUMENTO
                               where i.COD_DOCUMENTO == item.TIPO_DOCUMENTO
                               select i).FirstOrDefault();

                oEmpleado.ID_EMPLEADO = servicio.COD_EMPLEADO;
                oEmpleado.NOMBRE_CARGO = Cargo.NOMBRE;
                oEmpleado.NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO = tipodoc.NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO;
                oEmpleado.NOMBRE = item.NOMBRE;
                oEmpleado.ROL = item.ROL;
                oEmpleado.APELLIDO = item.APELLIDO;
                oEmpleado.CEDULA_EMPLEADO = item.CEDULA_EMPLEADO;
                oEmpleado.CELULAR = item.CELULAR;
                oEmpleado.CARGO = Cargo.COD_CARGO;

                oEmpleadoDTO.Add(oEmpleado);
            }
        }
        return oEmpleadoDTO;
    }
```